# Comparing of null and nullable values after translating from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to translate the following VB.Net code into C#:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", res_ID)
Dim m1 As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
If m1 Is DBNull.Value Or Nothing Then
   m1 = 0
Else
   m1 = 1
End If
```

In particular, I'm stuck with the following line:

```
If m1 Is DBNull.Value Or Nothing Then
```

I've attempted to translate it like this:

```
If (m1 == (DBNull.Value || null))
```

However, that gives me the following error:

> CS0019 Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DBNull' and '<null>'

How can I properly check in C# whether `m1` is either `null` or `DBNull.Value`?

Comment: That VB.NET code should not be translated because it's buggy. It should be: `If m1 Is DBNull.Value OrElse m1 Is Nothing Then`. In your code the `Nothing` will be compiled to `False` because that's the default value of `Boolean`

Comment: It's running a database query, and if the value it gets back is dbnull or actual null (Nothing), sets the value to 0. Otherwise sets it to 1. Which frankly is kinda silly, but what do I know  =)

Comment: Yes, it is kinda silly but it works. That code works with two kinds of databases with various count of fields inside. If we're querring database which lacks certain fields, the result is nothing. Reasult also could be dbnull and in both cases m1 should return 0. If query returns a real value we'll have m1=1.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) pointed out in the comments, your original code is subtly incorrect. It's not doing what you think it's doing.

To quote [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355172/comparing-of-null-and-nullable-values-after-translating-from-vb-net-to-c-sharp/50384485#comment87726702_50355172):

> That VB.NET code should not be translated because it's buggy. It should be: `If m1 Is DBNull.Value OrElse m1 Is Nothing Then`. In your code the Nothing will be compiled to `False` because that's the default value of `Boolean`

Which means that your code is *actually* compiled to:

```
If m1 Is DBNull.Value Or False Then
```

An expression of the form `x Or False` is logically equivalent to `x`. Thus, your inclusion of `Or Nothing` has no effect on the expression. Taking Tim's suggestion:

```
If m1 Is DBNull.Value OrElse m1 Is Nothing Then
```

Might make it a bit clearer how to properly translate this to C#. The equivelant code is:

```
if (m1 == DBNull.Value || m1 == null)
```

Answer (score -1):

in `C#` you can check easily by :

```
 if (m1 == null || m1 == DBNull.Value)
```